# Are there different "types" of moderators on Stack Exchange Network sites?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators

I see moderators referred with different terms on meta:

1. Moderator ("mod" or "Diamond Moderator" in some places)
2. Community Moderator

Are these different types actually?

I am aware that moderators are elected through election process every year.

But, are some of the Stack Exchange company employees also appointed (bypassing election) as moderator? If yes:

- are they still called Community Moderators? Or is there different term to call them?
- how to identify them on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) page?
- do they have any additional privileges than those are elected?

Comment: In order of power: unregistered users, low rep users, high rep users (2k/10k/25k etc, the “milestone” badges), diamond moderators (normally elected, sometimes for beta sites appointed), community managers, other SE staff. The last three groups all have diamonds in their usernames.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: 'community moderators' is actually *not* a term for the *site moderators*. The users of the site are the community moderators, moderating by voting and flagging and closing.

Comment: @DanBron almost... Community Managers will have diamonds as generally they're responsible for over seeing all sites on the network... other staff may or may not have a diamond depending on if it's required for their role... (if they don't need one, they don't get one...)

Comment: Here is stack snippet I wrote that lists users with a diamond that are also an employee: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304217/158100

Comment: @DanBron: _The last three groups all have diamonds in their usernames._ And that was why my confusion. Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two kinds of moderators, in a sense:

1. The *site moderators*. These are sometimes referred to as *elected* or *appointed* moderators (depending on how they were given the responsibility), as well as *community moderators* (with or without the 'elected' part). They are also called *diamond* moderators, because of the addition of the ♦ to their display name.

   On new sites, where the community is too small to hold an election, moderators are [appointed under *pro-tempore* terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188059/what-is-the-constable-badge).

   See the [help centre article on site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) for a description of what a site moderator can do, or look at the [long list of site moderators across the network](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). The central uber-Meta site also has a [FAQ section on site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role).
2. *Normal users* that have gained [some or all of the *moderation* privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), so the privileges marked with the [image: up-down arrows icon] icon in the list. They are sometimes called *trusted users*, but that's also the name of [*one* of the  moderation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

   The actions these users take is often referred to as *community moderation*. We ask the community to help keep the site clean, and with more reputation, you are given more options to help out with.

Confusingly, the term *community moderators* is also used in some places to refer to either site moderators or to the community members using their privileges.

This is all orthogonal to the employees of Stack Overflow, the company. Some employees hold diamonds too (and some even do so on *all* the site in the network, usually because they are members of the [Community Managers team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)), but not all employees do.

Comment: The use of "community moderators" to refer to elected moderators dates back to [the initial Theory of Moderation blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), ten years ago. Though the terms have never really been precisely nailed down.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: yeah, the terms are confusing. I don't think I can quite pin 'community moderators' on the community even now, so I altered this.

Comment: The today's [improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator?cb=1) will be further helpful...

Answer (score 8):

There are two types of moderators:

- [Community Elected Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) (elected by the community during annual/semi-annual elections).
- Moderators Pro Tempore; these are moderators who are appointed by the Stack Exchange team for a new or nascent site until it has the critical mass it needs to elect its own moderators.

There are others who have diamonds but aren't moderators, these include:

- Stack Exchange staff
- Community Management Team (also Stack Exchange Staff)

The part that is somewhat confusing to outsiders is Stack Exchange staff also have the (moderator) next to their name in their profile; meaning that have moderator abilities and powers, but it doesn't necessarily mean they'll partake in moderation.

There are also members of the community ("Trusted members") who have access to some moderation tools by virtue of their reputation; these individuals help by flagging and reviewing flags to ensure the most important stuff is put in the moderator queue; and the stuff that the community can handle is handled by them.

This [Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) has more information.